# Mail() in php do not send when \n character in header

Tags: email

I've some scripts like this one to send emails:

```
$content = "<html><head><title>xxxxx</title></head><body>blabla</body></html>";
        $headers ='From: "'.$email_auteur.'"<'.$email_auteur.'>'."\n";
        $headers .='Reply-To: '.$email_auteur.''."\n";
        $headers .='Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"'."\n";
        $headers .='Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit';
        mail("toto@mymail.com", "Subject", $content, $headers);
```

All scripts like this one worked fine. But I change the server (same OS (Debian)) and now these script don't work anymore. I've noticed that if I remove the \n at the end of this line:

```
$headers .='Reply-To: '.$email_auteur.''."\n";
```

It works!...
But I have tons of this script running on the server, so it is too fastidious to correct them all. Where can I find some conf to accept this character please?

Comment: What sort of error does the mail server give you when rejecting this?

Comment: I can't see any error in mail.info, mail.log ... Anywhere else too look?

Comment: So you say it doesn't send, something has to return an error, be it apache (httpd log) or sendmail (usually mail.log)..

Comment: I think I've found something: in procmail.log: `From www-data@xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu  Tue Feb 18 12:18:40 2014
 Subject: Subject
  Folder: /home/xxxxx/homes/xxxxx/Maildir/.spam/new/139272232    3460
Time:1392722320 From:toto@gmail.com To:ccccc@ccccc.com User:xxxx.yyyyy Size:3526 Dest:/home/xxxx/homes/xxx/Maildir/.spam/new/1392722320.14963_0.ns403668.ip-37-187-135.eu Mode:Spam`

Comment: spamassassin is stopping it... Only when \n character is set... How to allow it?...

Comment: What rule is it hitting on, that should be contained in the headers of the email..

Comment: `0.0 FREEMAIL_FROM          Sender email is commonly abused enduser mail provider
                            (toto[at]gmail.com)
-0.0 NO_RELAYS              Informational: message was not relayed via SMTP
 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE           BODY: HTML included in message
 1.1 MIME_HTML_ONLY         BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
 2.5 FSL_MISSP_REPLYTO      Mis-spaced from and Reply-to
 2.5 TO_NO_BRKTS_FROM_MSSP  Multiple formatting errors
 0.4 FROM_MISSPACED         From: missing whitespace
 4.4 FROM_MISSP_FREEMAIL    From misspaced + freemail provider`

Comment: It's the FREEMAIL trio that is tripping you up, you could alter the scores, but I think that might honestly do more harm than good. If you are sending crap email (and From with extra spaces qualifies) you should really fix the problem, not modify things which point out that problem.

Comment: I know but I have hundreds of scrips to modify... I don't understand why before it was ok... On the other server...

Comment: I don't know if the mail server and the web server are the same machine, but possibly you excluded locally generated mail from spam scans, or at least mail in the local network if they were separate.

Comment: Either way, if this mail has to go out to the world, your server will NOT be the only place those rules are configured, and you need to correct the problem, not hide it. Is the file always the same name in your web hosts?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, the mails can be sent worldwide... :-( 
The file is not the same, no... Hundreds of different files containing this... I'm looking to find a regex with sed to replace all

Comment: Are the lines always the same? Or do you have some variation in the $ values used?

Comment: Yes, just the variable is changing

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the php documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php, you should separate the headers with \r\n instead of \n (unless using a buggy mail transfer agent that double encodes it).

According to https://issues.apache.org/SpamAssassin/show_bug.cgi?id=6864 you are getting marked as spam because you don't have a space between `"` and `<` in the `From` header.

You should add a space in the From header, this should be enough to get rid of the spam score.

From:

> $headers ='From: "'.$email_auteur.'"<'.$email_auteur.'>'."\n";

To:

> $headers ='From: "'.$email_auteur.'" <'.$email_auteur.'>'."\n";

Actually, you shouldn't use the email address as display name, so if you haven't got anything relevant to use as display name just use:

> $headers ='From: '.$email_auteur."\n";